# DatePicker value after manual input

Tags: javascript, datepicker, shieldui

I'm using a 0:dd/MM/yyyy as format and textTemplate for the DatePicker object

```
$('#datePickerSelector')`.shieldDatePicker({
     format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
     textTemplate: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
});
```

When the user select the date from the selector in the proper way the format is correct when I retrieve the value using:

```
$('#datePickerSelector').val();
```

But whenever the user manually type in the date in the text box (for example 1/5/2015, the value retrieved using the same sentence above is (05/01/2015).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thinking that your using SheildUI for Datepicker, use $("#datePickerSelector").swidget().value(); to get the value

Comment: @ShankarUs Yes I am using ShieldUI, I tagged it, unfortunately the value is still incorrect (the default format MM/dd/yyyy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [parseFormats](http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/datepicker/javascript/api/settings/parseformats) option of the [datepicker](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/datepicker/basic-usage). It contains an array which contains list of date formats used to parse the value set with value() method or by direct typed user input. In your case you need to add dd/MM/yyyy in the array:

```
$('#datePickerSelector').shieldDatePicker({
        format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
        textTemplate: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",
        parseFormats: ["dd/MM/yyyy"]
    });
```